# What's the meaning of "I can't get the drinks out"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-irishman

In [The Irishman (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Irishman), Jake asks Jimmy a bridge loan:

> Jake: I got the first topless act on the Strip. I'm telling you, we're
>   booming in there. **I can't get the drinks out**...Just asking for a golf
>   course.

What's the meaning of "I can't get the drinks out"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an abbreviated sentence.

What he's trying to say is...

> I can't get the drinks out fast enough to satisfy the demand.

Essentially he's saying that the place is incredibly successful.